# RecyclerView issues: EditText loses focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've put some `EditText` in `RecyclerView` because I need to get some values. The implementation is this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@id/firstrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/rectable"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/table_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp" />
```

and this is the custom xml with some `editText`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="60dp ">


<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<View
    style="@style/VerticalSeparator" />


<EditText
    android:hint="lol"
    android:id="@+id/weight"
    android:focusable="true"
    style="@style/DefaultEditCellStyle" />

<View
    style="@style/VerticalSeparator" />

<EditText
    android:hint="lol"
    android:id="@+id/arm"
    android:focusable="true"
    style="@style/DefaultEditCellStyle" />

<View
    style="@style/VerticalSeparator" />


<EditText
    android:hint="lol"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/moment"
    style="@style/DefaultEditCellStyle" />
```

practically when I click on an `EditText` it opens keyboard, lose focus and close keyboard immediately, so it's impossible to write in these. I also tried reading other question, to put this:

```
recyclerView.setFocusable(true);
        recyclerView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but, at different of `listview`, it doesn't work.

How could I solve this issue? 
Thank you

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: @Anu yes, see solution below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I've solved it using this:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

in RecyclerView's layout and I add it in the Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use proper implementation in xml code, then this problem can be solved easily.
Here I have found a nice example [Android Recyclerview with edittext](https://demonuts.com/android-recyclerview-with-edittext/)

They solved this problem.
Here are some of the source code

xml code for recyclerview row item

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="TextView:"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/editid"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="hello"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Parsania Hardik on 17-Apr-18.
 */

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList;


    public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<EditModel> editModelArrayList){

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.editModelArrayList = editModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.editText.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue());
        Log.d("print","yes");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return editModelArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        protected EditText editText;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);

            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                      editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

As per above code, edittext values are controlled in the adapter class to remove focus and scrolling problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

From your manifest on the activity itself should be sufficient to solve the keyboard

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, it will help someone: use `notifyItemRangeChanged()` instead `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter class.